# How do I overwrite the Symfony2 semantic configuration per environment?

Tags: symfony

parameters.yml:

```
time_limit:        8
```

my_ui.yml:

```
my_ui:
    time_limit: %time_limit%
```

config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: my_ui.yml }
```

I can then access this fine in my controller via the Extension and Configuration classes in my bundle.

How do I now overwrite the `time_limit` in my test environment?

I've tried loading another `my_ui_test.yml` in the `config_test.yml` file but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out: you must have one parameters file per host. But I need different parameters per env on one host.

parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    time_limit: 8
```

my_ui.yml:

```
my_ui:
    time_limit: %time_limit%
```

config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: my_ui.yml }
```

That gives me `8` in `dev` env.

Then, parameters_test.yml:

```
parameters:
    time_limit: 0
```

config_test.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters_test.yml }
```

That gives me `0` in `test` env.

Comment: it actually is the answer to his question, which is allowed and encouraged on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Override any parameter in your `config_test.yml` file and make sure you make requests to the `app_test.php` controller when executing functional tests. If that controller doesn't exist, copy it from `app_dev.php` changing

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

to

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('test', true);
```

For example, I use the bcrypt password encoder that causes passwords to be encoded in 1-2 seconds each time. This is not acceptable for tests, so I override the cost to the minimal value in `config_test.yml` to speed up tests:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Elnur\Model\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 4
```

This way in production the cost would be `14`, but in testing just `4`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the need for another FC. Running `bin/phpunit` correctly sets the env to `test`?

Comment: Depends on whether you're doing unit or functional testing. If the tests are functional, you have to do requests to a front controller and that front controller better be `app_test.php` that's set up for the `test` environment. And if you're doing unit testing, you should not care about the environment at all.

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov Where did you set your prod value then, inside the config_prod or is it still in security ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is setting up your own functional test environment for testing. This is completely seperated from your prod / dev environment.

You can study nice examplse of this approach in Johann Schmidts bundles. I copied and adapted the one from the [JMSPaymentCoreBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSPaymentCoreBundle/tree/master/Tests/Functional) for my projects.

An other approach is to include (and override prod and dev settings) int he config_test.yml file. This file should be loaded by the test client only.

Comment: I tried the overriding of the values in `config_test.yml` directly, and did not work. Can you explain more?

Comment: Please show the test which is not working. And explain how you are executing it.

Comment: Setting up the dev and test environments seperately is what I'm hoping to avoid. Out of curiosity: how is TDD done then with Symfony2?

Comment: BetaRide, I don't think I understand: the test is working. This is about loading configuration semantically per environment (on same host)

Comment: Then you can use pure unit tests (ihneriting from PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase only). Obviously you will have no access to any configuration and have to mock everything. If you want to make use of a set-up Symfony stack, have a look at the docs at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests and use one of the mentioned methods to set-up your test environment.